# SQL Update statement to count hours in a shift from midnight

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that returns shift hours and Shift_Type against an employee
If a shift goes over 2 days and there is a Public Holiday rate across one of the days, I want to count the hours of the Public Holiday part of the shift.
Result would be in column PH_DAY

SQL Server 2014

Shift_StartTime    Shift_EndTime    Start_WeekDay    End_WeekDay    PublicHoliday    Shift_Type    Start_Time    End_Time    PH_DAY

Shift_StartTime |Shift_EndTime  |Start_WeekDay  |End_WeekDay    |PublicHoliday  Shift_Type  Start_Time  End_Time    PH_DAY
2/01/2017   3/01/2017   Monday  Tuesday 2/01/2017   PHS 22:00   6:00    2
26/01/2017  27/01/2017  Thursday    Friday  26/01/2017  PHS 23:00   7:00    1

I want to use an UPDATE statement to update the PH_DAY column with the count of the hours.  This one returns an error

UPDATE  tbl_Employee_Hrs

SET [PH_Day] = Count ('24:00')) - Start_Time)

WHERE Shift_Type = 'PHS' and (PublicHoliday = Shift_StartTime)

Comment: Knowing what kind of error would help other users answer your question. Also consider providing the schema of the table you're updating (column names and data types), as well as the version of SQL Server.

Comment: Format that code, please. Also provide a sample data set and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
    UPDATE Training.dbo.ShiftTable
    SET PH_Day = (
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME, PublicHoliday, 103) = Shift_StartTime 
            THEN DATEDIFF(hh, CONVERT(DATETIME, PublicHoliday, 103), (CAST(Shift_StartTime AS datetime) + CAST(Start_Time AS datetime)))
         WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME, PublicHoliday, 103) = Shift_EndTime 
            THEN DATEDIFF(hh, CONVERT(DATETIME, PublicHoliday, 103), (CAST(Shift_EndTime AS datetime) + CAST(End_Time AS datetime)))
    ELSE 0
    END
)
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit the data into a table ,  Error Message:  Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.                    The format of the columns: Start_Time and End_Time is:  convert (varchar(5), ru.fldEndTime, 108)       I think that is what is causing the mismatch of the format

Comment: What are the data types of the Shift_StartTime, Shift_EndTime, PublicHoliday,  Start_Time and End_Time fields in tbl_Employee_Hrs?

Comment: Hey MayowaO, thanks for sticking with me, I've been away for the day and there is an obvious time difference between us.  Shift_StartTime and Shift_EndTime is datetime   PublicHoliday is varchar(15); Start_Time and End_Time is varchar(5)  The last 2 was to achieve just a time display without the date.    Thanks

Comment: It is all good...keeping my brain busy! I assumed the PublicHoliday is datetime. I have updated the script. Please give it a go.